# android: Smoothest and most efficient way to animate drawn circles on a canvas

Tags: android

What is the best way to draw circles on a canvas that should have an alpha layer and change sizes? Should I use a View or a Surfaceview? The circles should also be clickable. And it should be smooth transitions when changing color size and position?

Should I put this in a runnable or use invlaidate in onDraw?

I would prefer that something like this also worked smoothly in low-end devices.

Any suggestions? I'm new to this kind of animations in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are constantly drawing and taking user input at the same time, I would use a SurfaceView. However, if the only draw changes you plan on making to the circles happen when you touch them, then a simple View onDraw() override would probably do the trick. In the end it will just depend on what all is going on.

The point of the SurfaceView is to have that separate thread for drawing. If what you're doing could be in any way considered "game-like," then go for a SurfaceView; otherwise, stick with a View.

I say this because I'm currently working on a project with constant drawing using a View. The shapes that I'm drawing respond to touch and you can scroll through the View while it is still invalidating over and over. All this with a View and it still runs just fine on lower-end devices (I've only gone back to GingerBread, though).

Good luck!

I should also mention that in the project drawing in a View, almost everything has various alpha values and what not and runs fine.